# Transform date format keeping its type python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, date, datetime

I have a date and I would like to change its format.

```
date = '2018.01.02 00:00'
```

`type(date)` return `str`

I would like to transform my date so that it is in format `'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` but still be **str**.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `datetime` for that:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.strptime('2018.01.02 00:00', '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M').strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
# '2018-01-02 00:00:00'
```

Comment: since the OP seems to need isoformat as output, even shorter: `datetime.datetime.strptime('2018.01.02 00:00', '%Y.%m.%d %H:%M').isoformat(' ')`